# Throwing a Validation Error in MVC without a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, view, controller

I have a View that is strongly typed to one model but has a form on it to post to a different model. I need to send a validation error back when a user leaves a note blank but cannot figure it out.  Here is the Form in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketId)*@
            @Html.Label("New Note", new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextArea("Note", new { cols = 600, @rows = 5 })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserTicket(Guid id, string Note)
{
    if (Note != "")
    {
        AddTicketNote(Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"] as string), id, Note, true);  
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EditUserTicket", id);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest strongly typing it to avoid this entirely, if possible. Just create a NoteViewModel and add an instance of it to whatever model the parent has. Then just use a required attribute and ValidationMessageFor for a simple solution.

Comment: @br4d This is for a help desk software that I am creating.

The reason I didn't do that is Above is a Ticket table that is attached to the model that is strongly typed to the view.  Then below the form is a list for all the notes attached to this ticket.  This form in the middle is so the user can add a new note to the ticket.

Is there a way I can still do that with a view Model?

Comment: Yes I think so Jamie, I am working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this.
This is what I would do:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketId)*@
        @Html.Label("New Note", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextArea("Note", new { cols = 600, @rows = 5, id = "noteArea" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<script>
$(function() {

    $('#submitBtn').click(function (e) {
        if($('#noteArea').val() == "")
        {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Please enter a note"); //You could append some HTML somewhere (I dont like alerts)
        }
    });  
});
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUserTicket(Guid id, string Note)
    {
        if (Note != "")
        {
            AddTicketNote(Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"] as string), id, Note, true);  
        }
        TempData["NoteError"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("EditUserTicket", id);
    }
```

Then in your `EditUserTicket` ActionMethod check if `TempData["NoteError"]` is not null and check the value. If it's not null and true then the note is empty.

In my opinion you shouldn't just do client side or server side. If you are going to do validation you should do it client **and** server.

Answer (score -1):

you can always use the client side jquery for validation that came with the asp.net mvc.

make sure in **BundleConfig.cs** jquery.validate is include and call the bundle in the layout.

then in your view

```
    $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validator = $("#myForm").validate().form();
        if (validator) {
                //do something you can alway send to server and do another validation
        }
    });
```

dont forget in your form **@Html.ValidationMessage** for each field you want error to appear

Comment: don't you read the quote inside my code if he want he can always send ajax back to server and do another validation